# Error in creating pivot table in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I get an error when i try to run the code below. Could anyone please explain why i get the error on the last part when the code tries to create the pivot?

Error says: "Invalid procedure call or argument" in the last part where i set pvt

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String

For Each PT In Sheet5.PivotTables
    PT.TableRange2.Clear
Next PT

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
  SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("B7:D10").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
  StartPvt = Sheet5.Name & "!" & Sheet5.Range("B12").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

MsgBox StartPvt & "_" & SrcData

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
    Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="TestPivotTable")

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact line where the error occurs? And what does the error message say?

Comment: Error says: "Invalid procedure call or argument" in the last part where i set pvt.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is struggling to handle the `SrcData` and `StartPvt` being stored as string as it is expecting a range. 
This does exactly the same as yours but it stores the ranges as `Range`s and converts them into strings only when needed.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim SrcData As Range, StartPvt As Range
    Dim PT As Variant

    For Each PT In Sheet5.PivotTables
        PT.TableRange2.Clear
    Next PT

    'Determine the data range you want to pivot
      Set SrcData = ActiveSheet.Range("B7:D10")

    'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
      Set StartPvt = Sheet5.Range("B12")

    'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
      Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=SrcData.Address)

    MsgBox StartPvt.Parent.Name & "!" & StartPvt.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "_" & _
           SrcData.Parent.Name & "!" & SrcData.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
        Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
        TableName:="TestPivotTable")

End Sub
```